# why am I getting Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route <- AppController even after adding the dependency in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I tried almost everything thats available on stackoverflow since none worked posting the same. Really sorry if found duplicate.

I am trying to reset the content of my Bootstrap table on the button click using the function `$route.reload()` but when I add it within the click function and even after adding the dependency I get the error  `Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route <- AppController` I am really unsure why am I getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
<button ng-model="NewDataSet" ng-click="ReloadTable();">Reset</button><br/>
```

Angularjs:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CopyToClipboard','ngRoute'], function() {});
app.controller('AppController2', function($scope,$http,$location,$anchorScroll,$copyToClipboard,$route){
 $scope.ReloadTable =   function(){
        console.log("JRJRJ");
        //$window.location.reload();
        $route.reload();
}   
})

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CopyToClipboard','ngRoute'], function() {});

app.controller('AppController2', function($scope,$route){
    $scope.ReloadTable  =   function(){
        $route.reload();
    }   
})
```

I tried lot of things as mentioned in the other answers such as:

1. I have added the cdn to my HTML file
2. I tried adding the dependency like this:

   ```
   app.controller('AppController2',['$route', function($scope,$route){

       $scope.ReloadTable  =   function(){
           $route.reload();
       }

   }]);
   ```
3. I checked out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOivhAKBVUU). He seems to be doing almost the same but working for him but not for me.

As I ran out of ideas I thought of posting to get some idea/suggestions from you guys.

**Based on the comment:**

Following are the Angularjs CDN that I am using in my HTML file:

```
<!-- Angularjs CDN Starts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angularjs CDN Ends -->
```

Comment: which version of angularjs are you using now?

Comment: I am using the 1.4.8 angularjs. I have added all the 3 CDN links in the above question that I am using.

Comment: I suggest to use all the same version in this case `1.4.8` so to avoid inconsistent issues

Answer (score 0):

```
Would you please try below.      
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CopyToClipboard','ngRoute'], function() {});
    app.controller('AppController2',['$scope','$http','$location','$anchorScroll','$copyToClipboard','$route', function($scope,$http,$location,$anchorScroll,$copyToClipboard,$route){
     $scope.ReloadTable =   function(){
            console.log("JRJRJ");
            //$window.location.reload();
            $route.reload();
    }   
    }])
    
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CopyToClipboard','ngRoute'], function() {});
    
    app.controller('AppController2', ['$scope','$route', function($scope,$route){
        $scope.ReloadTable  =   function(){
            $route.reload();
        }   
    }])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have tried this already actually. But I tried again by adding all the dependency within the `[]` as well as in the `function` parameter but I am getting the error: `ReferenceError: $route is not defined`. This error is different than I was receiving previously.

Comment: Can you please also share something that we can replicate your issue? Codesanbox is a good tool for this. Then we can help you.

Comment: for the angular router pls use  this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js instead of  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js